# What software is used to create these kinds of infographics and checklists?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, information-graphics, information-design

What software is generally used to create these kinds of infographics or checklists? What do you guys use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - glad to have you here! Please look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community, and what we're about. Look at [ask] and [answer] questions, to learn how to frame acceptable queries and what to expect of replies and answers; please also look at [help/behavior] to understand our community's internal behavioural expectations.

Comment: Just about any software *could* create those. The only difference would be *how* in a specific application.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* decent vector art software would work for those tasks: [**Adobe Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html), [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/), [**Xara Designer**](https://www.xara.com/us/designer-pro/), [**Inkscape**](https://inkscape.org/), or if you're on a Mac, [**Sketch app**](https://www.sketchapp.com/), though most often used for UI design tasks, would also work admirably for these tasks.

Inkscape is freeware (and fully open-source, same on Windows, Mac and Linux), the rest are a range of prices and values.

The differentiation between each is based mostly on workflow preferences, and so some extent feature list/bloatware aversion, UI elegance and underlying graphics engine speed, and for Adobe and Affinity, interconnection with other tools in their proprietary software ecosystem.

My history on this: I was for ***decades*** a *dedicated* Adobe Illustrator user (who had shifted from Macromedia Freehand *prior* to the Adobe-Macromedia purchase due to preference for Illustrator's much smoother IMHO workflow); I developed (and purchased) huge content libraries of Adobe-centric stuff, taught use of the big three (Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign) in a corporate setting, helped small design firms adopt their use; developed architectural illustration workflows, and then... Affinity Designer came out. I evaluated it, and was blown away by how much faster and smoother it was. When I realised the price was both perpetual licensing and fractional cost relative to Adobe, I made the jump. It's still a product in active development - there are some specific tool and features yet upcoming on the roadmap, but *I've* not been unhappy to have made that jump.

That said, again, the differentiation is really down to personal preference, workflow and cost: ***ANY*** of them will succeed in the tasks about which you're enquiring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll have a look at them and see which one is beginner friendly.